# Select2 clear icon overlapping with text in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I'm having an issue where the text is overlapping under the hovering X "clear" button in the select menu. Adding padding to the right isn't a solution, as it pushes the icon outside of the box. I'm using the Select2 JS library found here https://select2.org/ and Bootstrap 5

```js
$("#search_bar").select2({
  theme: 'bootstrap-5',
  placeholder: "Some text",
  allowClear: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.2.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.min.css" />

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="">
  <select id="search_bar" class="form-select w-25">
    <option value="1">
      This is a long option string
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      This is another long option string
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is that the text size of option can be long and potentially unpredictable.  Why not increase the width to like `w-50' or even 100% ?

Comment: @Shaunak that doesn't necesarrily solve the problem just makes it harder to notice - a sufficiently long string of text will still have this issue. Also I have the select box as long as it can be for the UI of my page, the w-25 was just to illustrate easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the document here [Select2 Docs](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width). You can extend the select2 width, using the `width: 'style'` and inline style in the tag `<select>`. Here I set the width of the select to `200px`

Then, by looking into the DOM structure of the select2 (using Chrome Devtool), I see that we can make the X button not overlap the text by adding this CSS:

```
.select2-selection.select2-selection--single {
  padding-right: 50px !important;
}
```

```js
$("#search_bar").select2({
  theme: 'bootstrap-5',
  placeholder: "Some text",
  allowClear: true,
  width: 'style'
});
```

```css
.select2-selection.select2-selection--single {
  padding-right: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.2.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.min.css" />

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="">
  <select id="search_bar" class="form-select w-25" style="width: 200px">
    <option value="1">
      This is a long option string
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      This is another long option string
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work reliably, there's a small breakage at a specific odd screensize but I believe that's poor formatting in my own UI. Thank you for this! Marked as solved

Answer (score 0):

add the following css.

```
    .select2-selection__clear {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 2px !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8n23bd6q/

Comment: That gives a little bit of a funky result sadly, it's very close to the dropdown icon. Ideally I want the text to be offset but I'm not sure how to do that